# net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED when using react with redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, axios

action.js

```
import Axios from 'axios';
import { PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL, PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST, PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS } from '../constraints/productConstraints';

const listProducts = () => async (dispatch) => {
try {
    dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST });
    const { data } = await Axios.get('http://localhost:3001/product');
    dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS, payload: data });
}
catch(error) {
    dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL, payload: error.message });
 }
}

export { listProducts }
```

home.js

```
const Home = () => {
const productList = useSelector(state => state.productList);
const { products, loading, error } = productList;
const dispatch = useDispatch();
useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(listProducts());
    return () => {

    }
},[]);
}
```

when I use axios.get('/product') it works but when I use axios.get('http://localhost:3001/product') it shows error GET http://localhost:3001/product net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED don't why I am getting this error API is not hitting

Comment: Do you have `proxy` property in your `package.json`?

Comment: No i don't have

Comment: It is solved just changed Axios to axios and it worked

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already done so, add `"proxy": "http://localhost:3001",` to your `package.json` in your React app.